# Remove Duplicate Records Except One Record

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table that has multiple duplicate records as the following:

```
ID      Title
-----------------
1       Article A
2       Article A
3       Article B
4       Article C
5       Article A
```

In the above case, i need all duplicate titles and leave one only.

Article B and Article C are fine.
I need to remove Articles A, except one.

Sample output:

```
ID      Title
-----------------
1       Article A
3       Article B
4       Article C
```

Note: i'm not concerned about which ID to keep or remove. All i want is one record to be pertained.

Assuming i have huge bulk of records that has duplicate titles

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DELETE 
   t1 
FROM 
   tTable t1, tTable t2 
WHERE 
   t1.fieldName = t2.fieldName AND t1.id > t2.id
```

### ELSE

create another table as below

```
CREATE TABLE myTable_new (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Title varchar(20))
```

and add values as

```
INSERT INTO myTable_new  (ID, Title) SELECT ID, DISTINCT Title FROM old_table
```

considering `old_table` is the earlier table...

Answer (score 6):

This will always leave the row with the lowest ID -

```
DELETE t2
FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN `table` t2
    ON t1.Title = t2.Title
    AND t1.ID < t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE Title = 'Article A' AND ID <> 1
```

Just choose an ID to keep.

Comment: How come i couldn't figure this out...I guess i'm exhausted...Thanks!

Comment: Assuming i have huge bulk of records that has duplicate titles, i believe i would need subquery in someway or another.

Comment: I would look after the titles which are represented more than once in the table and then i would iterate throgh the result set and clear out the unnecessary rows.

Comment: what if I have new row as `6       Article B`??

Comment: DB will have to be monitored/checked every period of time to remove duplicates...

Comment: Before you indert a new record in this table you schould check first an existing equal record. You can set up an UNIQUE constraint also for Title column

Comment: Yea, this is a good idea but i already have over 100k records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint over the `Title` column, ignoring duplicate key errors:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE my_index (Title)
```

Of course, such a constraint will also prevent further duplicates from being added to the table in the future; if you do not wish to enforce such a constraint in the future, you can simply drop the constraint after it has been created:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX my_index
```